# Using a data.frame as a function argument gives invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, list, function, lapply, sapply

New to R here.

I have a list similar to this below as a part of an assignment.

```
irisL <- split(iris, iris$Species)
```

I want to use this list to compare Sepal.Length within the three species setosa, versicolor, and virginica.

I have written this function, which compares the species two at a time.

```
similarity <- function(x,y){
incommon <- intersect(irisL[[x]][1],irisL[[y]][1])
all <- union(irisL[[x]][1],irisL[[y]][1])
percentage <- 100*(nrow(incommon)/nrow(all))
return(percentage)
}
similarity('setosa','versicolor')
```

This works and gives the numerical output I want, but requires that one manually compares all possible sets of two species. I have then, **as instructed in the assignment given**, written this function within a lapply and sapply function as seen below.

```
sim <- lapply(irisL, function(x){
sapply(irisL,function(y){
incommon <- intersect(irisL[[x]][1],irisL[[y]][1])
all <- union(irisL[[x]][1],irisL[[y]][1])
percentage <- 100*(nrow(incommon)/nrow(all))
return(percentage)
})
})
```

This should go through the irisL list one species after another and then compare to the same irisL list. The output I want from this is a 9x9 list with a percentage for each comparison.
However, I get the error:

```
Error in irisL[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I am not sure why this is happening since irisL[['setosa']], irisL[['versicolor']] etc. all are data.frames. Also, I'm supposed to write the function inside the lapply-sapply environment, so the solution should include these two.

I've tried searching on this site but I haven't yet found an answer that helped. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Within the function in your `lapply` code, replace `irisL[[x]]` with `x`.

Comment: to expound on r2evans comment `lapply()` is working like a type of for loop, with the first argument as its range of itteration. `sapply()` is, more or less, a type of `lapply()`. Try instead changing the `irisL` in `lapply(irisL` and `sapply(irisL` to `lapply(1:length(irisL),` and `sapply(1:length(irisL),`